# Thread Quantum?

Tags: multithreading, language-agnostic

What is a thread quantum, and how can I identify it on my system?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thread Quantum is the amount of time that the schedule allows a thread to run before scheduling a different thread to run.

[What are threads?](https://web.archive.org/web/20100505225310/http://www.codeguru.com:80/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/article.php/c4009)

[Platform Builder: Setting the Default Thread Quantum](https://web.archive.org/web/20200811045019/http://geekswithblogs.net/BruceEitman/archive/2009/10/13/platform-builder-setting-the-default-thread-quantum.aspx)

As far as editing goes...There is a registry setting in windows that allows priority changing:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE / SYSTEM / CurrentControlSet / Control /
> PriorityControl / Win32PrioritySeparation

0 Foreground and background applications equally responsive

1 Foreground application more reponsive than background

2 Best foreground application response time

Answer (score 3):

Check out this [tutorial on thread quanta and scheduling](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/thread_scheduling_2.shtml)

In particular:

> Each thread has a quantum, which is effectively how long it is allowed to keep hold of the CPU if:
>
> it remains runnable;
>
> the scheduler determines that no other thread needs to run on that CPU instead.

Comment: the second point seems a bit strange to me, because if no other thread needs to run on that CPU, then there is no need for a quantum, but the thread should just keep hold of the CPU until some other thread needs to run on that CPU

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number the quantum could be infinite in that case, but it still exists from a theoretical standpoint :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to identify, but I know what a Thread Quantum is.

Multithreading, or parallelism in general, is not "true" parallelism on a single-core computer (nor it is on a dual-core when there are more than 2 threads, nor it is on a quad-core when there are more than 4 threads, etc.).

The Operating System keeps track of a list of threads. Each thread has a priority. The list will execute the topmost thread on the list. The thread will execute for as long as allowed by the Thread Quantum. When a thread is finished executing, it will move down to the bottom of the list.

Thread Quantum will determine how long a thread may run on a sequential system. Higher priority threads have higher Quantums and thus run longer.

Answer (score 1):

Give a look at Round Robin Scheduling

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_scheduling

I think this may be what you are asking about. quantum is the unit of time give to each process to execute.

Answer (score 0):

How do you measure length? velocity? mass? It is the same thing with threads and processes.

A **quantum** is a unit of time. Programmers don't talk about the time that each thread is supposed to work in seconds, milliseconds or microseconds but in *abstract* unit of time called quantum.

Comment: Actually a quantum is the MINIMUM unit of any measurable entity, not just time

Comment: From a pjysics perspective or windows?