# foreground threads vs background threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, scheduling

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339syd0.aspx) states that:

> Background threads are identical to foreground threads with one exception: a background thread does not keep the managed execution environment running

1. Is there any dereference in the [Thread Quantum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387980/thread-quantum) that given by OS to the thread if it were a background thread rather than the foreground threads? [Check this](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/thread_scheduling_2.shtml).
2. When setting a background thread priority to a higher value like `Highest`, will it get more quantum than a foreground one with lower priority?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if MSDN states there is no other difference why would you think there is?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Managed foreground/background threads, the Windows thread quantum and thread priority are orthogonal concepts.

- Being a foreground thread means that the process cannot be stopped until it (and all other foreground threads) are stopped.
- The quantum is the length of time a thread gets to run before the system will consider scheduling another thread on that processor.
- The thread priority determines the pecking order within all ready to run, waiting threads.

Of these three items, only foreground/background pertains to managed code.

Now to your questions.

1. The foreground process is a Windows concept. It is unrelated to foreground/background threads in .net.
2. Thread priority does not affect the quantum.